# How can I get all 4 × 4 submatrices of an n × n matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, combinatorics

I have a square matrix, I need to extract all possible combinations of 4 × 4 submatrices, where $n > 4$. For example in the case of a 6 × 6 matrix, there are 15 4 × 4 submatrices. I need the list of all 4 × 4 submatrices.

I tried with Subsets but I get matrices of 4 × 6.

Comment: isn't the case that there are only 9 4x4 matrices?

Comment: I think so, in my problem the combination of 6 in 4 is 15 but there are degeneration then there are 9 4x4 matrices. How can i get those 9 matrices?

Comment: I get 225 4x4 submatrices from a 6x6 matrix.

Comment: If you have a 6X6 matrix and you want get a 4x4 matrix you must delete 2 rows and 2 columns. The possible columns that you can delete are the following two rows: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (4,5), (4,6), (5,6). Therefore there are 15 possibility for the rows and the same for the columns. Therefore the number of possible 4x4 submatrix of 6x6 matrix are 15*15=225.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Subsets`:

```
mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##]&, {6, 6}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ mat
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
fourbyfours =  mat[[#, #]] & /@ Subsets[Range[6], {4}];

TeXForm[Grid @ Partition[MatrixForm /@ fourbyfours, 3]]
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,2} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

Alternatively, you can use [`Minors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html):

```
pminors = Diagonal @ Minors[mat, 4, Identity];
pminors == fourbyfours
```

> True

If  you want submatrices with consecutive indices:

```
fourbyfoursconsec = Join @@ Partition[mat, {4, 4}, {1, 1}];
Length@fourbyfoursconsec
```

> 9

```
TeXForm[Grid[Partition[MatrixForm /@ fourbyfoursconsec, 3]]]
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
>  a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: I tried with Subsets, but i get 4x6 matrices, I need 4x4 matrices

Comment: @Elvis, pls see the updated version.

Comment: `Minors[]` is definitely the correct function to use here.

Comment: Shouldn't the number of submatrixes of a 6 * 6 matrix be `Binomial[6, 4] Binomial[6, 4]`.

Comment: @Gowiththewind, right. There are  225 4X4 submatrices and `Minors[mat, 4, Identity]` gives all of them. (15 of these have identical row and column indices; and 9 of the latter have consecutive indices.)

Comment: @kglr Thanks the first way is the one I needed. I needed the 15 matrices  that had identical row and column indices

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = Array[a, {6, 6}];

Join @@ Table[mat[[j ;; j + 3, k ;; k + 3]], {j, Length@mat - 3}, {k, Length@mat - 3}]
```

> $\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} \\
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
>  a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} \\
>  a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} \\
>  a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} \\
>  a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} \\
>  a_{6,3} & a_{6,4} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$

Answer (score 2):

Might not be so elegant, but try this:

```
(* create a test array *)
startingArray = ArrayReshape[Range[36], {6, 6}];
startingArray // MatrixForm
all4x4 = Partition[Partition[#, 4, 1] & /@ startingArray, 4, 1];
MatrixForm[#] & /@ Flatten[Transpose[#] & /@ all4x4, 1]
```

This yields the expected 9 arrays.
[image]